# Help with Integral of Step Functions

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces

Find $\int f(x)g(x) dx$ in $L^2$

$f(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & a<x<b \\ 
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$ and $g(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & c<x<d \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Note: $a<b<c<d$

I know the bounds on the integral of $f(x)$ are $b$ (upper bound) and $a$ (lower bound) and similar for $g(x)$, $d$ (upper) and $c$ (lower). However how can I calculate this integral?

Comment: From the definitions of $f$ and $g$, it follows that $fg$ is identically zero.

Comment: is this due to that the two functions only agree when the value is 0?

Comment: The reason is explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that, since $a<b<c<d$, one has
$$
f(x)g(x) = \begin{cases}
0\color{red}{\,\,(=1\times 0)} & a<x<b \\ 
0\color{red}{\,\,(=0\times 1)} & c<x<d \\
0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$ giving
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\cdot g(x) \,dx =0.
$$